# Database Design for storing users achievements/scores for several reward types

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

**Background**

-I'm working on a system that allows a business to create several types of predefined rewards, for example:

- Rewards based on users visits
- Rewards based on cash spent.

-Each reward type has its own progress indicator:

- Visit rewards: count of visits
- Cash rewards: the cash amount

-The system must track and keep a log of the progress of each user for each type of reward

-When the user achieves the target for the reward and redeems it, the score for the reward type should be reset.

What is the best database design to implement this functionality? Having in mind that the design should aim for scalability to include multiple reward types in the future.

Comment: What's wrong with a database that has one row for each user and one column for each type of reward?

Comment: This approach is not recommended. I need to add a new column for each type of reward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be extensible you should just store individual values based on `userId-rewardId` combo:

```
CREATE TABLE reward_progress (
    user_id int NOT NULL, -- reference to the user
    reward_id int NOT NULL, -- reference to the reward (or code if you choose)
    val int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- value is tracked here
    date_achieved timestamp -- when reward conditions were met. NULL if not yet.
);

ALTER TABLE reward_progress
    ADD CONSTRAINT reward_progress_pkey
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id, reward_id); -- order is important here
```

Order is important here because you will be looking up rows by either `user_id` only ("give me all progress rows for given user") or by `user_id` and `reward_id` ("progress of given user in given area").